# Properly displaying a kml in google maps v3?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

In google earth there is a nice feature where I can install a kml file and it loads it in such a way so that I toggle different layers. In google maps I am looking for a way to display the kml file in a similar way. I want to have a sidebar where I can choose which layers to display. I have found this:

http://www.dyasdesigns.com/geoxml/

but it looks like it only works with google maps v2. Is there anything similar that will work with v3?

I found this QA, but I'm looking for something to use with V3

EDIT more info:
My body:

```
<body onload='load()' style = "height:100%; margin:0">
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
//************Function in head***************************************************
        function load() {

        var myOptions = {

        //change this to zoom with markers
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 5),
          zoom: 4,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),myOptions);
        ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://thoughtfi.com/NPDsFactGlobe.kml');
        ctaLayer.setMap(map);   
       }
    //load();

    var map;
    var ctaLayer;
    var markersArray = [];
    var startformat;
    var endformat;

</script>
</body>
```

a link to the site (may be up and down if Im working on it.): http://thoughtfi.com/KMLtries.html

A picture from google earth. I want the functionality of the folders in the left column: http://thoughtfi.com/desired_look.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=google+maps+v3+kml+parser

Ross/Udell: http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/
Lance Dyas's replacement for geoxml: http://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/

Others are probably available too.

Comment: thanks, I'm having some trouble implementing this. Do you know of any examples?

Comment: Larry Ross has examples using the first one: http://www.geocodezip.com/ and scroll down to geoxml3.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the `google.maps.KmlLayer`[<sup>api-doc</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlLayer) class? It provides a way to load, display, and hide KML files using a standard in-library facility. An introductory tutorial on using the `KmlLayer` is provided in the [**KML and GeoRSS Layers** section of the Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers).